# sock = new UdpClient(ipAny) cause error > System.Net.Sockets.SocketException has been thrown. Access denied

Tags: unity-game-engine

My Environment

```
MacOS X 10.8.5
Unity 5.1.1f
```

I am trying to use code to access NTP server.
http://ftvoid.com/blog/post/847

When I try the code, I have an error at `new UdpClient(ipAny)`

```
private void Request() {
    // Open socket
    ipAny = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 123);
    sock = new UdpClient(ipAny);
```

The error message is

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException has been thrown
Access denied
```

Instead of the following

`sock = new UdpClient(ipAny);`

if I use the following, it works.

`sock = new UdpClient();`

My Questions are

1. What's the cause of the error?
2. Is it O.K. to use `sock = new UpdClient()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be fine.  The constructor you are using is for local port binding.  Not sure why you need that.  From the docs:

> You do not need to specify a local IP address and port number for sending and receiving data. If you do not, the underlying service provider will assign the most appropriate local IP address and port number.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k227d11f(v=vs.110).aspx

I'd use the `new UpdClient()` as you suggested.

Comment: Thank you for the link and your comment. As I search with google, the error seems to be related to binding. I will proceed with new UpdClient().